# filter multidimensional associative array with multidimensional associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

i have two multidimensional associative arrays, but i want to get data that only have similarities.
this is an example of my data array.

```
$data = array(
           array("id"=>"1","dress_color"=>"Red","size" => "L"),
           array("id"=>"2","dress_color"=>"Blue","size"  => "L"),
           array("id"=>"3","dress_color"=>"Blue","size"  => "S")
        );
```

I want to filter the associative array with a similar array.

```
$match = array(
            array("dress_color"=>"Red","size" => "L"),
            array("dress_color"=>"Blue","size" => "L")
        );
```

and the output I expect the data to be is this.

```
$expected = array(
           array("id"=>"1","dress_color"=>"Red","size" => "L"),
           array("id"=>"2","dress_color"=>"Blue","size"  => "L"),
        );
```

I hope for help from all my colleagues, I'm having trouble with this part

Answer (score 0):

```
$filtered = array_filter($data, function($input) use ($match) {
                $arrayData = [];
                foreach ($match as $value) {
                    if($input["dress_color"] === $value["dress_color"] && $input["size"] === $value["size"]){
                        $arrayData[] = $input["dress_color"] === $value["dress_color"] && $input["size"] === $value["size"];
                    }
                }
                return $arrayData;
            });
```

i trying, and success

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP array_intersect() function that should do what you want.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php